# How to filter a (a,b) relation by (b,a)?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a generic relation A like this:

```
DUMP A;
(a, b)
(a, c)
(a, d)
(b, a)
(d, a)
(d, b)
```

See that there is the pair (a,b) and (b,a); but there isn't a pair for (d,b).
I want to filter those "unpaired" tuples out.

The final result should be something like:

```
DUMP R; 
(a, b)
(a, d)
(b, a)
(d, a)
```

How can I write this on PIG?

I was able to solve with the following code, but the cross operation is too expensive:

```
A_cp = FOREACH L GENERATE u1, u2;
X = CROSS A, A_cp;
F = FILTER X BY ($0 == $3 AND $1 == $2);
R = FOREACH F GENERATE $0, $1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the output of my `DESCRIBE A ; DUMP A ;`:

```
A: {first: chararray,second: chararray}
(a,b)
(a,c)
(a,d)
(b,a)
(d,a)
(d,b)
```

This is one way you could solve this:

```
A = LOAD 'foo.in' AS (first:chararray, second:chararray) ;
-- Can't do a join on its self, so we have to duplicate A
A2 = FOREACH A GENERATE * ;

-- Join the As so that are in (b,a,a,c) etc. pairs.
B = JOIN A BY second, A2 BY first ; 

-- We only want pairs where the first char is equal to the last char.
C = FOREACH (FILTER B BY A::first == A2::second)
    -- Now we project out just one side of the pair.
    GENERATE A::first AS first, A::second AS second ;
```

Output:

```
C: {first: chararray,second: chararray}
(b,a)
(d,a)
(a,b)
(a,d)
```

**Update:** As WinnieNicklaus points out, this can be shortened to:

```
B = FOREACH (JOIN A BY (first, second), A2 BY (second, first))
    GENERATE A::first AS first, A::second AS second ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your code.
I was able to do the task with the following code, but the cross operation is too expensive:

A_cp = FOREACH A GENERATE u1, u2;
X = CROSS A, A_cp;
F = FILTER X BY ($0 == $3 AND $1 == $2);
R = FOREACH F GENERATE $0, $1;

Comment: @user2730009 The inner join should be significantly less expensive.

Comment: Why `JOIN` with just one key and then have a separate `FILTER`?  You can just do `B = JOIN A BY (first, second), A2 BY (second, first);`

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus Didn't know I could do that... Seems like I still have a long way to come :P.